# C/C++ Dereference error: Dereference before null check

Tags: c++, c, pointers, operating-system, embedded

In the function below I am facing a Dereference error before null check. In the line

```
SEC_KM_KEKColumn_t *pAdmin1KEKs = pTCGKS->keySet[SEC_KM_Admin1].kc;
```

There is an error which states directly dereferencing pointer pTCGKS. And also in the line

```
SEC_ASSERT_MODEL(pDefaultKS != NULL && pTCGKS != NULL);
```

there is an error which states Dereference before null check (REVERSE_INULL)
check_after_deref: Null-checking pTCGKS suggests that it may be null, but it has already been dereferenced on all paths leading to the check.

```
Stat_t SEC_COD_SLOW SEC_KM_TCG_Activ(SEC_KM_TCGKeySet_t *pTCGKS, uint32_t rangesSUM, SEC_KM_DefaultKeySet_t *pDefaultKS)
{
   Status_t status = STATUS_OK;
   uint32_t rangeIndex = 0;
   const SEC_KM_KDF_t *pDigestNID = SEC_KM_GetAnybodyDigest();
   SEC_KM_KEKColumn_t *pAdmin1KEKs = pTCGKS->keySet[SEC_KM_Admin1].kc;
   const SEC_KM_KDF_t *pDigestAID = SEC_KM_TCG_GetSessionCredentials();

   SEC_ASSERT_DEBUG(SEC_KM_TCG_GetSessionUserID() == SEC_KM_Admin1);
   SEC_ASSERT_MODEL(pDefaultKS != NULL && pTCGKS != NULL);

   // Generate Key Chains for all TCG authorities for Original Opal scheme
   status = SEC_KM_TCG_Generate(pTCGKS, pDigestNID, pDigestAID);
   if (status != STATUS_OK)
   {
      return status;
   }

   // Rewrap SDEK from default key storage into Global Range of TCG
   status = SEC_KM_RewrapSDEK(&pDefaultKS->SDEKw, &pDefaultKS->keySet.RKEKw, &pDefaultKS->keySet.PKEKw, pDigestNID,
                              &pTCGKS->DEK[GDEK].SDEK.w, &pAdmin1KEKs[RKEKG].w, &pAdmin1KEKs[PKEK].w, pDigestAID);
   if (status != STATUS_OK)
   {
      return status;
   }

   status = SEC_KM_TCG_ConvertToSUM(pTCGKS, pDigestNID, rangesSUM);
   if (status != STATUS_OK)
   {
      return status;
   }

   // After Activation all ranges are unlocked. So unwrap all SDEKs.
   for (rangeIndex = 0; rangeIndex < TCG_MAX_RANGE_KEYS; rangeIndex++)
   {
      status = SEC_KM_TCG_UnwrapUnlockedSDEK(pTCGKS, rangeIndex);
      if (status != STATUS_OK)
      {
         return status;
      }
   }

   return status;
}
```

Comment: The null check should really come before the first use of pTCGKS in the function. It looks like you passed a null into the function for whatever reason. We have no way of knowing what happens from what you posted.

Comment: Sounds like you are passing a null pointer to `SEC_COD_SLOW SEC_KM_TCG_Activ` as the first parameter.  Can we get a [mre]?

Comment: What's the question?

Comment: Since you tagged as C++, you should look into the "smart pointers".

Comment: It is either C or C++ it cannot be both - pick one.  What are you compiling it as?

Answer (score 5):

It's exactly what it says.

First you dereference `pTCGKS`, then you check that it isn't null.

Compilers can ([and will](https://unicode-org.atlassian.net/browse/ICU-20065)) optimise out a "late" null check as being effectively redundant for any well-defined program, making your assertion potentially useless.

Move it to before your dereference.

Answer (score 0):

The `SEC_ASSERT_MODEL` checks for `NULL` *after* the line that references it. If `pTCGKS` is null a runtime error will occur before that check, so it serves no useful purpose.

I assume `SEC_ASSERT_MODEL` is a precondition check macro - if that is the case you need  to perform those checks *before* using the checked parameters:

```
   SEC_ASSERT_DEBUG(SEC_KM_TCG_GetSessionUserID() == SEC_KM_Admin1);
   SEC_ASSERT_MODEL(pDefaultKS != NULL && pTCGKS != NULL);

   Status_t status = STATUS_OK;
   uint32_t rangeIndex = 0;
   const SEC_KM_KDF_t *pDigestNID = SEC_KM_GetAnybodyDigest();
   SEC_KM_KEKColumn_t *pAdmin1KEKs = pTCGKS->keySet[SEC_KM_Admin1].kc;
   const SEC_KM_KDF_t *pDigestAID = SEC_KM_TCG_GetSessionCredentials();
```